# Airflow creates duplicate SubDAG runs after scheduler restarts

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow version 1.10.3 installed on python 3.6.5.

I have a DAG definition that consists of several bash and python operators, as well as some SubDAG operators. The DAG is scheduled to run every minute, with `max_active_runs` set to 1, and `catchup` set to False (cron-like).

From time to time I find myself having to restart the Ariflow scheduler (for example, to enable a configuration change). If this happens while the SubDAG is in running state, I see some weird behaviour:
The SubDAG and its parent DAG are still running (as can be seen in the UI under `Browse --> DAG Runs`, as well as the running processes list on the machine running Airflow). After several minutes I get a notification stating that the SubDAG task (the task inside the parent DAG that is running the SubDAG) is detected as a zombie. This causes the scheduler to mark the parent DAG as failed, and continue to reschedule in after one minute.
However, when this happens, I can clearly see that the original SubDAG is still running, and after the parent DAG is rescheduled, I suddenly have 2 running instances of the SubDAG (even though I set `max_active_runs` to 1).

I have set up a small example to reproduce this behaviour:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow-test',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['your.email@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

def make_subdag():
    with DAG(
        'dag-test.subdag',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1),
        concurrency=5,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False,
        orientation='TB',
    ) as subdag:
        BashOperator(
            task_id='subdag_task',
            bash_command='while true; do echo ping && sleep 10; done',
        )
    return subdag

with DAG(
        'dag-test',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=1),
        concurrency=5,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False,
) as dag:
    dummy_task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='dummy',
    )
    subdag_task = SubDagOperator(
        task_id='subdag',
        subdag=make_subdag(),
    )
    dummy_task >> subdag_task
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Add the python file containing the DAG definition to your DAGs folder
2. Start the airflow scheduler
3. Unpause the DAG
4. Wait for the DAG and SubDAG to reach a running state
5. Restart the scheduler by killing its active process and then starting it up again (NOTE: only kill the scheduler, not the running jobs for the DAGs and their tasks)
6. Wait the amount of time specified by `scheduler_zombie_task_threshold` in `airflow.cfg` (default 5 minutes)
7. You should now get an email notification stating that the SubDAG task was detected as a zombie, and soon after you will see the SubDAG having 2 running jobs (in the DAG runs table of the UI).

Is this some sort of bug with Airflow, or am I missing something with my configuration and/or DAGs definition?

Comment: I have the same issue running Airflow 1.10.12 on kubernetes